# Unity Tilemaps, Single Tile Collision detection for highlighting Tiles/Cells, strange behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid, collision, tile

Ive been working for a few days on this problem, trying to create a square grid of tiles, using Unity Tilemaps seems to be the most efficient way, and it has a lot built in already.

I want to highlight the tiles around the player so that he will see what the legal moves are.
I use a second Tilemap for this, on top of the basemap(ground/grass).

The second Tilemap, the highlightsMap is made up of invisible Tiles, which will turn into highlighted Tiles when a `Physics.SphereOverlap` occurs, or a `Physics2D.CircleAll`

To detect every Tile, I have added a box collider on an empty object and I made a grid of these colliders on top of the Tilemap grid, so that:

`Box Collider at Position (2,4,0)`    is exactly on top of `Tile at Position(2,4,0)`

This should be the most straightforward way to handle this, as you can change a Tile, using `Tilemap.SetTile(Vector3Int Pos, Tile tile)`

The problem is very strange however. The colliders have the correct positional values to be able to reference the tiles exactly underneath them, just through that position data. As explained above, and I have double checked this, the collider empties have the exact same position as the tiles underneath them, no conversion is needed.

The problem is that the tiles are not highlighting around the player as expected, instead a few next to the player are highlighted and others arent, the Physics.OverlapSphere I am using only works on 3D Colliders, which is why I added them as another grid on top of everything.

Using Physics2D.CircleAll, unfortunately does not detect any 2D colliders on the tiles themselves(Sprite, or Grid), not sure if that is intended to work like that anyway.

Collision Grid Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class scr_ColliderGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject eCollider;
public Tile invisibleTile;
public Tile highlightTile;
public Tilemap highlightMap;
public int xSize, ySize;

private Vector3Int[] gridArray;                 // Tilemaps use Vector3Int BUT only use (X, Y, 0)   !!!!!!!
private int xC = 0, yC = 0, i = 0;

private Tile[] tiles;

private Vector3Int previous;

private void Start()
{
    gridArray = new Vector3Int[xSize * ySize];
    tiles = new Tile[xSize * ySize];

    GenerateCollisionGrid();
}

private void GenerateCollisionGrid()
{
    for (xC = 0; xC < xSize; xC++)
    {
        for (yC = 0; yC < ySize; yC++)
        {
            Vector3Int newPos = new Vector3Int(xC, yC, 0);       // 2, 4, 0
            Vector3Int newColPos = new Vector3Int(xC, yC, 0);    // 2, 4, 0     //This used to be different values, but now they are exactly the same.
            if (invisibleTile != null)
            {
                Tile tile = Instantiate(invisibleTile, newPos, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                tiles[i] = tile;

                GameObject col = Instantiate(eCollider, newColPos, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            }
            gridArray[i] = newPos;
            i++;
        }
    }

    highlightMap.SetTiles(gridArray, tiles);
    highlightMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(2,4,0), highlightTile);   // 2,4,0  //Test to see if positions are the same. (collider and tiles)
}
```

Player Highlight Legal Moves Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class scr_TankMoves : MonoBehaviour
{
public Tile highlightTile;
public TileBase[] highlightTiles;
public Tilemap highlightMap;
public int maxMoveTiles;
public bool highlight;

private Vector3Int previous, previousLeft, previousRight, previousForward, previousAft, previousVect;
private Vector3Int[] previousVectors;

void Start()
{

}
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x,
                                         transform.localPosition.y + 1,
                                         transform.localPosition.z );
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x,
                                         transform.localPosition.y - 1,
                                         transform.localPosition.z );
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x + 1,
                                         transform.localPosition.y,
                                         transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x - 1,
                                         transform.localPosition.y,
                                         transform.localPosition.z);
    }
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (highlight)
        HighlightMoves();
    else EraseHighlights();
}
private void HighlightMoves()
{
    previousVectors = new Vector3Int[1];
    highlightMap.SetTiles(previousVectors, null);

    int tMax = 0;
    
    Collider[] legalTiles = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, maxMoveTiles/2);
    previousVectors = new Vector3Int[legalTiles.Length];
    foreach (Collider col in legalTiles)
    {
        //Vector3 conversionVector = new Vector3(col.transform.localPosition.x, col.transform.localPosition.y, col.transform.localPosition.z);
        Vector3Int tileVector = Vector3Int.FloorToInt(col.transform.position);
        previousVectors[tMax] = tileVector;
        tMax++;
    }
    highlightMap.SetTiles(previousVectors, highlightTiles);
}
private void EraseHighlights()
{
    //highlightMap.SetTile(previousForward, null);
    //highlightMap.SetTile(previousAft, null);
    //highlightMap.SetTile(previous, null);
    //highlightMap.SetTile(previousRight, null);
    //highlightMap.SetTile(previousLeft, null);

    highlightMap.SetTiles(previousVectors, null);
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, maxMoveTiles/2);
    }
}


    }
```

If you open a new 3D Project in Unity and setup a grid with a Tilemap, called highlightMap in my code example, you should be able to recreate this exactly, using the 2 scripts.

Everything is oriented in 2D, this means `x+ is Right`  `y+ is forward` and `z+ is up/dephth` (unused by tilemaps).

The empty Collider prefab I have is an empty GO with pos 0,0,0. it has another empty GO Child, which has the Box Collider Component, and the transform value of this child is 0.5,0.5,0.5, so that the Collider is centered on top of each tile.

This is after 0 moves, so just pressed Play:
[image]

This is after 1 move forward, (y+1):
[image]

Comment: Careful: Afaik the `Tilemap.SetTile(Vector3Int Pos, Tile tile)` parameter `Pos` refers to the **grid position** .. which might be different to the actual **world** Vector3 position (transform.position) of the colliders ... did you check if they are actually in the correct places?

Comment: And yes make sure you go with one physics engine ;) Physics and Physics2D are two completely separate engines and in no way connected to each other! If you go with Physics.OverlapSphere you will need 3D `Collider`s .. if you want `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` you will need 2D `Collider2D`s (in 2D the Z axis bascially doesn't exist) ... your screenshots look like you rather want to work in 3D

Comment: yes a 100% they are in the correct place, when I highlight that Tile at pos (2,4,0) and then go through my array of emptyColliders in the hierarchy, the emptyCollider at position (2,4,0) is exactly on top of that highlighted Tile(2,4,0) so it is exactly as it should be, but im thinking adding these 3d colliders is a mess, is there no built in way to check for nearby tiles? I was just getting the Tile the player is on and adding/subtracting from that to highlight the Tiles around that center one, but thats also a mess and doesnt allow for scalability, this is why I want to use a Sphere/Circle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going by colliders at all afaik you could also just use [`GridLayout.WorldToCell`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html) like e.g.

```
Tilemap yourTileMap;

// see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap-layoutGrid.html
var grid = yourTileMap.layoutGrid;
// The "Grid" implements "GridLayout"
// see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Grid.html
var currentCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position);
var currentCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(currentCellPos);
```

Then if you need to get multiple tiles I would probably go the "lazy/stupid" way and just do something like e.g.

```
var currentCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position);
var currentCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(currentCellPos);

var leftCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position - transform.right * someRange);
var leftCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(leftCellPos);

var rightCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position + transform.right * someRange);
var rightCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(rightCellPos);

var frontCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position + transform.forward * someRange);
var frontCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(frontCellPos);

var backCellPos = grid.WorldToCell(transform.position - transform.forward * someRange);
var backCell = yourTileMap.GetTile(backCellPos);
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, but unfortunately this doesnt get the adjacents tiles. Same problem remains, getting the center tile is easy, but extrapolating that to get the adjacent tiles is a mess if you do it manually by subtracting and adding to it, especially if you want the player to have 30 legal moves or so. I really need it to work with a Sphere/Circle collisions so that the radius can easily be changed for different classes.

Comment: I was doing it that way before, but like I said its not scalable at all, maybe you can do a for loop to cycle through but still it will be a lot of code for every tile and it will be very confusing. This way with colliders is much better for scalability and less code, because once it works all you need to do is change the radius! Anyway I found out what was wrong! Thanks a lot for always helping me derHugo you are a boss!

Answer (score 0):

```
  highlightTiles[tMax] = Instantiate(highlightTile, col.transform.parent.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

I dont know why, but apparently I didnt instantiate the tiles themselves into an Array of tiles, so everytime I was ''placing'' them on the grid, it was actually placing an empty array.
Now its fixed! Just need to find a nice way to erase all after a move and im set!